# What's the difference in meaning and formality between these questions?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, spoken-english, formality

> A. "You're feeling a little nervous, aren't you?"
>
> B. "Feeling a little nervous, are you?"
>
> C. "A little nervous, are you?"

My questions are:

Are B and C correct?

Is there a change in formality between the three senteces?

Is there a difference, though little, in meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A could be a kind, sympathetic enquiry. B and C are more casual (they use fewer words) and could seem less sympathetic. It all depends on the tone of voice and the relationship between the speaker and the person addressed. There is no difference in meaning.